# How to extract the elements of an Array[String] in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

Suppose we have an Array:

```
val arr = Array("Id:1; Apple; Red; 2; Out",
                "Id:2; Banana; Yellow; 5",
                "Id:3; Peach; Red; 3",
                "Id:4; Grape; Green; 5; Out")
```

I want to apply a function on each element of the array, which extracts the fruit type and the number and returns a Map. The output in this case would be:

```
(Apple, 2)
(Banana, 5)
(Peach, 3) 
(Grape, 5)
```

I tried:

```
val pairMap = arr.foreach(r => r.split(";")(1) zip r.split(";")(3))
```

but I always obtain `Unit`

Comment: That's because `foreach` returns `Unit`. Use `map` instead. You might also want to parse the numbers into integers (right now you will get strings).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually have two errors in your code.

First as pointed out already you are using foreach (which returns `Unit`) instead of map (which returns an `Object`).

Second, you are using `zip` in your `foreach` function, which combines two collections pair wise, like this:

```
val arr1 = Seq("Apple", "Peach", "Banana")
val arr2 = Seq("Red", "Red", "Yellow")

val arr3 = arr1 zip arr2 // = Seq(("Apple", "Red"), ("Peach", "Red"), ("Banana", "Yellow"))
```

Your code should look like this:

```
val arr = Array("Id:1; Apple; Red; 2; Out",
  "Id:2; Banana; Yellow; 5",
  "Id:3; Peach; Red; 3",
  "Id:4; Grape; Green; 5; Out")

arr.map(r => (r.split(";")(1), r.split(";")(3)))
```

Or to be a tiny bit more efficient, by splitting only once:

```
arr.map { r =>
  val t = r.split(";")
  (t(1), t(2))
}
```

And you probably don't want the white spaces, so:

```
arr.map { r =>
  val t = r.split(";")
  (t(1).trim(), t(2).trim())
}
```

Just adding this because I think regex is also a good option for string processing and a neat feature together with scala's pattern match:

```
val regEx = "[^;]+; ([^;]+); [^;]+; ([^;]+).*".r

arr collect {
  case regEx(fruit, number) => (fruit, number)
}
```

Also leads to the desired output, but might be a bit overkill for this simple use case.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this. Thank you!

Comment: This is a correct solution, in the sake of efficiency one further thing would be to not traverse the collection twice by using `map` two times.

Comment: For the regex solution, do you just have to add parentheses around the element which you want to extract?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's called a capture group ( a general regex thing ). But you need to be careful in case you have an element that does not match, you might want to add a default case in the pattern matching. Otherwise you will get a scala.MatchError exception. I changed the code to use collect, which will just go over non matching elements and ignore them

Answer (score 1):

Close, but you should have used `map` instead of `foreach`.

Both these *higher-order functions* take a function and apply that to each element of the collection.

The difference between the two can be seen in the (simplified, not actual) signature:

```
trait Collection[A] {

  def map[B](f: A => B): Collection[B]

  def foreach(f: A => Unit): Unit

}
```

The difference is that `foreach` is used to make some sort of action or *side effect* happen (e.g. printing), while `map`ping yields a collection whose elements are those of the starting collection with the function applied:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).map(_ * 2).forech(print) // prints 2468
```

Furthermore, the function has to be edited a little bit in order to work as intended:

```
arr.map {
  row =>
    val split = row.split(";") // split only once
    (split(1).trim, split(3).trim) // no zipping necessary
}
```

`zip` is not necessary because you are already processing each item, one at a time, while `zip` allows you to *zip* together two collection.

```
Seq(1, 2, 3) zip Seq('a', 'b', 'c') == Seq((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')) // true
```

Comment: If I use map, I receive: `pairMap: Array[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Char, Char)]] = Array(Vector(( , ), (A,2)), Vector(( , ), (B,5)), Vector(( , ), (P,3)), Vector(( , ), (G,5)))`